# How to download files from storage

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, firebase-storage

I have files in my firebase storage. I want to be able to download a file button click.

For instance

```
<button (click)="download()"></button>
```

And component class :

```
download(){
   const file_url = 'audio/7ejhsjd';
   // Change file name
   //download file
}
```

I would like to change the filename (metadata) of file then download it.

How can I achieve this in JavaScript or TypeScript?

Answer (score 2):

```js
function download(){
   const file_url = 'https://www.google.com.ua/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png';
   var el = document.createElement('a');
   el.download = file_url;
   el.href = file_url;
   document.body.appendChild(el);
   el.click();
   el.remove();
}
```

```html
<body>
<button onclick="download()">Download!</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Nice!. Is there anyway I can remain the file? Let say from ``googlelogo_color_272x92dp`` to ``Google Color Logo``.

Comment: not sure, probly not.
edit: oh, me telling lies: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download, if you work in same domain, you can set in `el.download ="filename.png"` / `<a download="filename.png">` resulting file name.